# When OpenSSL generates a RSA public key, default exponent is 65535, how can I change it?

Tags: openssl, rsa, exponent

[image]

I want to change the default exponent. What command should I use?

Comment: Please copy the text to the question. Text screenshots are not really welcome here. (not searchable and may go away)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

You've got 2 options for `genrsa` when you're generating the key:

```
-f4             use F4 (0x10001) for the E value
-3              use 3 for the E value
```

Other values are not really common.